# Bounded Sequence help

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

A series $\{S_n\}$ is defined as follows:
$$S_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n+n}.$$

Evidently this sequence is increasing as for every $a_n = (3^n+n)^{-1}$ is less than $a_{n+1}$.

However, how do you show that the sequence is bounded? Bounded below is simple as since it is an increasing function, it is bounded below by $S_1$. But what about bounded above? The calculator shows about $0.39$ as the upper bound.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Observe $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n+n} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Hint:

Since $3^n \leq 3^n + n$, we have the following inequality (working term by term):

$$\sum \frac{1}{3^n + n} \leq \sum \frac{1}{3^n}$$

Do you know how to show this new sum is bounded? In fact, you can compute the new sum exactly and see it's finite.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped me through it

Comment: Happy to help ^_^. If this answered your question you should mark it as such so other users know where to spend their time

Answer (score 0):

As $3^n$ quickly exceeds $n$, you can get tighter and tighter bounds by evaluating the first terms exactly and replacing the tail of the summation with larger terms $\dfrac1{3^n}$.

$$\frac1{3}\frac32=\frac12=0.5$$
$$\frac14+\frac1{3^2}\frac32=\frac5{12}=0.416666\cdots$$
$$\frac14+\frac1{11}+\frac1{3^3}\frac32=\frac{157}{396}=0.3964646\cdots$$
$$\frac14+\frac1{11}+\frac1{30}+\frac1{3^4}\frac32=\frac{2333}{5940}=0.3927609\cdots$$

These are *guaranteed* upper bounds.